# scratch sprite mosaic effect not working consistently

Tags: sprite, mit-scratch

I have a simple shooter game where a gliding sprite is supposed to shatter (using mosaic effect) when hit, then disappear. Problem is, the sprite only shatters and disappears maybe 1 time out of 5. Here's the relevant code snippet:

[image]

For more context, here's the link:
https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/524150880

Answer (score 0):

In the project, you're using set mosaic effect, not change mosaic effect. This makes it just do nothing and then hide.

Comment: I changed it to set mosaic effect, It's actually working as it should sometimes (i.e. shattering then hiding), just not all the time. So it's ok the few times when it does work.

Answer (score 0):

1. I replied to your other question on this project
2. Maybe you have to increase the delay, if it is .25s it is just a quarter of a second and players may not be able to see it. Try extending it!
3. If that is not the reason then I don't know

Comment: Sorry, that's not it either. Existing code works as it should, just not all the time, which is strange. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe it is a scratch 3 issue (if you used scratch 2 and then went to scratch 3) because I coded 1 of my projects in scratch 2 and then scratch 3 made it only work like 50% of the time (I highly doubt that is it, your code is still in scratch 2, but I'm saying maybe...)

Comment: You're right, I actually started the project in scratch 2, but it wasn't working 100% of the time so I tried upgrading to scratch 3, same problem. Still, these new releases are usually backward compatible, so that should not have been an issue.